# WorldPay Integration with Ionic 4, getting payment details through a provided template form

Tags: ionic4, payment, worldpay

So there is this Payment provider called World Pay, that enables applications to collect payment information via their own provided template form (https://beta.developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpop/template-form).

A working implementation of this for Angular can be found here:

[How to integrate worldpay with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506912/how-to-integrate-worldpay-with-angular2/47075980#47075980)

Using this code I’ve managed to get it working for Android (and on the browser), but not on iOS. More specifically on the iOs builds the template form does not load, I just get a blank page.

The error I get in the iOS logs is:

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'
```

I have added:

```
    <allow-navigation href="https://cdn.worldpay.com/*" />
```

into the config.xml and it has made no difference.

There is a lot of advise online to not use iframes on Ionic apps and to use the in cordova app browser instead, however I am not sure how to open the a browser page when all I have is the address of a script (https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.